# Method testCompile not recognized in android studio project using Gradle version 2.2.3?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I can't figure out this problem. I'm trying to start writing unit tests for my project using junit as per what the android developer pages recommend. In the top-level build file of my app I have a gradle file that looks like this:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And I get the following error when I try to do a Gradle project sync:

```
Error:(9, 0) Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [junit:junit:4.12] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

Comment: `// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files` - follow the advice and put them in your app build.gradle dependencies (I know what the developer page says, but it should work fine at app level, not top level gradle file)

Comment: Okay good to know, as you suspected I was following what the dev page said.

Comment: @MarkKeen Indeed, the developer page is still saying to put it at the top level gradle file, which would result in this Gradle project sync error and waste developers' time. Why on earth would the developer page suggest something like that?

Answer (score 3):

You are placing dependencies for `buildscript`. Usually, you should place dependencies there which you need for build lifecycle or plugin development.

You can actually fix this by moving `dependencies` block to the `allprojects` closure, for instance:

```
// ...
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
    }
}
```

But follow the advice of [Mark Keen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4252352/mark-keen) in the comments. It is not the best idea to place even common dependencies in the root `build.gradle` file.